# Chromatic number and vertex covering number

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

For any graph $G=(V,E)$ let $\tau(G)$ be the minimum cardinality of a [vertex cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) of $G$. Let $\chi(G)$ denote the [chromatic number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChromaticNumber.html) of $G$.

Is there a graph $G$ with $\tau(G) < \chi(G) - 1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S$ be a minimum vertex cover. Give every vertex of $S$ a different color. Finally give all vertices of $V-S$ the same, new color.

I trust, you can take it from here.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks!!